# FutureBuilder makes my app freeze because it waits for a file to load before building

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I am writing a very basic flutter app for reading public domain books. I included a .txt file containing a book in my app's assets. since a book is quite long and would take time to load I was trying to use a FutureBuilder that will display a circular progress indicator while the book is loading, however, when I click on the button to open the book the app freezes until the book is loaded instead of transitioning to the book page and showing a progress indicator while the book is loading as I would like.

I checked this for a smaller file and it didn't freeze. I tried to just tell the FutureBuilder to show the progress indicator and again, it didn't freeze.

```dart
FutureBuilder(
                  future: text, //Future<String>
                  builder: (context,snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.done) {
                      return Text(
                        snapshot.data,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),);
                    }
                    else {
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }
                  },

                )
```

It looks like the FutureBuilder is just trying to build with the text instead of building without it and adding it later like it is supposed to do. How do I tell it to do that?

Comment: So after some experimenting I have come to tha

Answer (score 2):

Dart is mostly single-threaded. So when you're reading the text, it's doing it in the same thread as the UI and that's why it's slowing it down. Using a future means that the call may be delegated to a later time (depending on how you schedule it), but it is still running in the same thread.

What you want to do is use an [Isolate](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.1/dart-isolate/dart-isolate-library.html), and do the file reading within that. Once you have the file (and do any processing you need to do), you should be able to pass it back to the Text class and it should be faster - although if you're dealing with a very large amount of text it may still stutter a bit as the Text class still has to process all the text. If it does stutter, I'd recommend breaking the text into parts (chapter/paragraph?) and using multiple text and/or richtext objects to display it in a list.

The easiest way to use an Isolate in flutter is the [`compute' function](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html).

Then your future will have something like this in it:

```
await compute(readFile, <path to file>);
```

Note that the input and output of `compute` have some limitations since it uses an [Isolate's SendPort](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/SendPort/send.html) under the hood:

> The content of message can be: primitive values (null, num, bool, double, String), instances of SendPort, and lists and maps whose elements are any of these. List and maps are also allowed to be cyclic.

Comment: This doesn't quite solve my problem, since I still don't know how to tell FutureBuilder to build first with a progress indicator and when the future finishes being executed, replace the progress indicator with the the contents of "text"

Comment: The function that calls 'await compute ....' will have to return a future - use that as the future you pass to the FutureBuilder

Comment: Your issue currently is that when you're reading the file it's on the UI thread and so blocks the UI for a period of time, and so what you with the future builder doesn't matter since it doesn't actually get to build (since the UI thread is blocked)

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is here:

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
  return Text(snapshot.data, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20));
}
```

The ConnectionState.done is set just after the stream is connected (I assume you're using a stream) so that condition is always true.
I think is better if you use the snapshot.hasData as validation like so:

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: futureStream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Text(snapshot.data);
      } else {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
    },
);
```

Comment: That won't really change anything as that's not the issue, although it is still probably a good idea to check `hasData` as you've suggested as if a future returns null, hasData may be false even in the state ConnectionState.done.

Comment: I am using a Future<String>