# Flutter: App freeze when loading images from API

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using FutureBuilder to get and load images from API, but when it tries to load images, the app freezes.

the Futurebuilder class:

```
new Container(
          child: new FutureBuilder<ProductsModel>(
            future: ProductsService.getProducts(),
            builder: (context, myData) {
              if (myData.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                if (myData.hasData) {
                  ProductsModel productsModel = myData.data;
                  List<Data> productsList = productsModel.data;
                  return new GridView.builder(
                      itemCount: productsList.length,
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 2),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return new ProductsCardsModel(
                          imageAddress: productsList[index].image,
                          title: productsList[index].title,
                        );
                      });
                } else {
                  return Text('There is no data show! :(');
                }
              } else {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            },
          ),
        )
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56485534/3390459

Comment: The problem is probably within `ProductsService.getProducts()`. Can you show that code?

Comment: @emerssso Fetching images from an API is an asynchronous task, and OP is correctly wrapping that task in a `FutureBuilder`. The problem is likely that he is doing something in the task method that is unnecessarily blocking the thread. Unless OP is also doing some heavy processing on the images or is downloading hundreds of them at once (and for some reason needs to do so), using an `Isolate` for this task is almost certainly overkill.

Comment: @Abion47
You can check my codes in my github repository:
https://github.com/YRlp98/charm_mehregan_mobile_app